# My layers will not ungroup

Tags: gimp, layers

Using Gimp 2.10

**In the layers panel**, all layers cannot be rearranged. I am trying to remove some from a group but cannot do so. Dragging has no effect and using the "up" or "down" buttons works but still stuck inside group.

Tried ignoring this and made new groups. But I cannot move any files into them.

What is going on?

This has **NOTHING to do with** the move tool and all layers are **NOT** locked in the Layers Panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the Microsoft Windows platform:

You are likely running into an issue with a third-party tool on your system, which uses full-screen transparent windows to achieve some kind of effect (e.g. screen tints or global gestures or screen recording). such windows make GTK, the user interface toolkit used by GIMP, think that the application windows are hidden behind other windows and cause it to ignore some events, like dragging. See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/1082 for details.

This is addressed by a change to GTK, which is included in the two most recent versions of the GIMP installer for Microsoft Windows, 2.10.24 revisions 2 and 3, so if you install that, the issue should be gone.

Comment: Please be patient with me here a sec. Can you please explain that like I'm a child because I have no idea what any of that means. I have autism and what I understood you saying was to just uninstall the gimp software I have I download and install a new one. I'm not sure that is what you meant, especially since my software was downloaded only 3 weeks ago.

Comment: @JacobChamp as a first step, it would be good if you can confirm whether you are using GIMP on a Microsoft Windows platform (this is Windows 10, for example), and what version you got installed - this can be seen in the dialog that is opened by the Help > About GIMP menu entry. It will contain something like "GIMP 2.10.24 (Revision 3)".